Determining all holomorphic functions that satisfy certain conditions
I came across a complex analysis exercise which I was not able to figure out.
Let $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ i - 1 , i + 1 , 2i \}$. Determine all functions $g \in H(\Omega)$ such that

$(i)$ $\lim_{z \to \infty } g(z) = 2i$

$(ii)$ $i-1$ is a pole of order $2$ with residue $e^{i3 \pi / 4}$

$(iii)$ $2i$ is a pole of order $3$ with residue $3$

$(iv)$ $1 + i$ is a removable singularity
I was not able to deduce much from the conditions. My attempt consisted in writing out laurent serieses around the poles: for example in $1 + i$ we actualy can write out a holomorphic function but I don't really have constraints on the coefficients of the series; in $i-1$ we can write the coefficient of the $-1$ index and have
$$\frac{e^{i3\pi / 4}}{z - (i -1)} + h(z)$$
with $h(z)$ a holomorphic function. But it does not seem to take me anywhere. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Thank you in advance.

Good start, what are you left with when you subtract the principal part of the Laurent series at the poles?
